# Compiler error - exe does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I have the compiler error shown in the image and am not able to resolve it - "Consults.exe does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point". My program does contain a Main method.

[image: The Error Message]

```
public static int Main(string[] args) 
{ 
    Program s = new Program(); 
    s.name(); 
    string d = Console.ReadLine(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Can you post your main method?

Comment: public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program s = new Program();
            s.name();
            string d = Console.ReadLine();
            return 0;
        }

Comment: Try removing `public` from the method. If it doesn't help - clean your solution (Build -> Clean Solution).

Comment: @user2320445 it is a static main.

Comment: @AlexSikilinda its not working

Comment: @AlexSikilinda i am also not able to set the startup object

Comment: try void main and remove return 0

Comment: @adaam you can check the main method
    `void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program s = new Program();
            s.name();
            string d = Console.ReadLine();
            
        }`

Comment: @AlexSikilinda same error.

Comment: add [STAThread] brfore main like this `[STAThread]
         static void Main() {}`

Comment: @user2320445 same error.

Comment: is it a windows from app

Comment: @user2320445 no, its not a windows form app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79253/discussion-between-lumiere-and-user2320445).

Comment: It should be `static void Main() { System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!"); }`.

Comment: @Claies I tried with `void` also. i got the same error

Comment: @Claies it is not important. void or int with return is allowed by the compiler.

Comment: What about setting the output to "Console Application"? Do you have it so?

Answer (score -1):

In a console Application, the compiler requires the Main() function to be void and not return any such value.

Comment: Never heard of this. Are you sure about your claim? _All_ my console applications return values from `Main`. See [this example](http://ideone.com/Pqi63n) as a proof-of-concept for returning values from `Main`.

Comment: No real set rule on it, but I've always worked on the best practice of this.

Comment: That's nonsense I'm afraid. It is clearly documented on MSDN that Main() functions may return an int value and console applications are specifically mentioned. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0fwzzxz2.aspx Indeed, its conventional for command-line utilities to return an integer code indicating success or failure (or truthiness) so that they can be used in conditional statements within scripts.